# What's the proper interaction between ScaleGestureDetector's new "quick scale" feature and a GestureListener's onDoubleTap()?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, gesture-recognition

The KitKat SDK supports a new type of scale gesture called [quick scale](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html#setQuickScaleEnabled%28boolean%29). Instead of requiring two fingers to pinch zoom, the user can doubletap and swipe to scale a view. You can see this in action in the Chrome and Maps apps.

Both Chrome and Maps differentiate between a doubletap (which zooms into the relevant content area, as before) and a doubletap-swipe (which allows you to scale arbitrarily with one finger).

Under the hood, the ScaleGestureDetector [uses a GestureDetector](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/5823352c6c5bfa3824afacd023b01af537b5dfa0/core/java/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.java#L462) to detect doubletaps and start looking for the corresponding swipe.

My question is how to mimic Chrome and Maps, detecting both doubletaps and this doubletap-swipe gesture but not both at the same time. That is, I'd like to differentiate between a normal doubletap (no swipe) and a doubletap-swipe.

I have both a GestureDetector and a ScaleGestureDetector being fed all touch events on my view. Currently, both GestureListener.onDoubleTap() and ScaleGestureListener.onScaleBegin() fire when I do a doubletap-swipe. onDoubleTap() gets fired first, so there's no way cancel handling events in the ScaleGestureListener.

I see two possible solutions, neither of which is very clean:

- Copy the ScaleGestureDetector from the Android source and add a new callback to the ScaleGestureListener interface for something like onDoubleTapConfirmed() (doubletap, no swipe).
- Add a small delay to onDoubleTap() so we handle the event X milliseconds after it gets triggered. If onScaleBegin() gets fired before the delay is up, cancel handling the onDoubleTap() event and start handling the scale instead.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with few flags:

```kotlin
var inQuickScale: Boolean = false
var inUnfinishedDoubleTab: Boolean = false

private inner class GestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        inUnfinishedDoubleTab = true
        inQuickScale = true
        return true
    }

    override fun onDoubleTapEvent(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (inUnfinishedDoubleTab) {
            if (e.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                inUnfinishedDoubleTab = false
                inQuickScale = false

                // Handle double tap here
                
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}

private inner class ScaleGestureListener : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {

    override fun onScaleBegin(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
        inUnfinishedDoubleTab = false
        return true
    }

    override fun onScaleEnd(detector: ScaleGestureDetector) {
        inQuickScale = false
    }

    override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
        if (inQuickScale) {
            // Handle quick scale here
        } else {
            // Handle regular scale here
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to this party, but the quick scale is more like an unfinished double tap on which the second tap turns into a drag, something like:

> tap down, tap up, tap down, move

It seems your interpretation of quick scale is:

> tap down, tap up, tap down, tap up, tap down, move

Which makes your problem a lot easier if you only register a plain double tap on the second action down. When the second action up happens, you just need to figure out whether a drag has happened during the second tap cycle. In case the gesture recognizers don't work for you, you can do that manually by checking against [getScaledTouchSlop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getScaledTouchSlop()).

Also, copying the ScaleGestureDetector is probably not as bad as you think - github is littered with "compat" projects that are basically backports of features in newer SDK versions.